# Chrome Keyboard shortcuts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get a keyboard shortcut to work and at this point I am just testing to see that pressing the shortcut works. So currently what I have it do is send a message to the background page that it is working but the key press never registers. I was wondering how to address this issue.

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "My Cool Extension",
"version": "0.3.1.5",
"description":"User can enter in wepage and press button to open webpage in new tab.",
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"]
},
  "content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "js": ["jquery-2.1.4.min.js", "content.js"]
}
],
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "arrow.png",
"default_popup":"popup.html"

},
"permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "storage"

    ],
"icons":{
     "128":"arrow.png"
},
"commands": {
"openSavedTab": {
  "suggested_key": {
  "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
  "mac": "Command+Shift+Y"
  },
"description": "Opens saved tab"
}
}
}
```

tab_shortcuts.js

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  chrome.tabs.update({}, function(tab) {
    if (command == 'toggle-pin-tab')
       chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log("Shortcut is functional");
       alert("working");
});
});
```

Comment: `chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener` works only in the `background` scripts.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just uploaded the code to github here [link](https://github.com/warrington1220/shortcutExtension). Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Except for the missing `arrow.png` the extension works: displays an alert on keypress and pins/duplicates the tab. If it doesn't for you, the only thing I can think of is that another extension has the same hotkey assigned. Or maybe it's another program on your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you wOxxOm for your help. You were right when you said the issue was with a conflicting extension with the same hotkey assigned. Once I disabled the extension my extension worked properly.